# Android 8 AOSP build question on prebuild .apk files

Tags: android, android-source, build-system

I'm working on an embedded system that uses/will use Android8. To date, development has happened on Android 7.1.1 -- the vendor of the reference board supports only those two.

In Android 7.1.1, we copied .apk files from our repository to the running system like so:

```
PRODUCT_COPY_FILES += foo.apk:root/foo.apk
```

(or the like.) This is completely disallowed by Android 8.

So, from the few google hits that got me info on the AOSP and not user info about Android phones, we are trying this (in external/foo/Android.mk):

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := foo 
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := foo.apk 
LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := APPS
LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := PRESIGNED

LOCAL_MODULE_SUFFIX := $(COMMON_ANDROID_PACKAGE_SUFFIX)

include $(BUILD_PREBUILT)
```

...no trace of any artifacts in the builds!

So, three questions:

1. Am I doing it right?
2. How can I turn on $(info foo) messages? They were on by default in our 7.1.1 environment but not in 8.
3. Our guide is *Embedded Android* by Karim Yaghmour. Is there a more up to date guide?

Thanks!

EDIT:  In response to a question, below, I will attempt to add the complete "make foo" output.  Note that this is mostly boilerplate that the distro, as modified from the reference board manufacturer, always spits out:

```
including device/asus/fugu/vendorsetup.sh
including device/fsl/imx6/vendorsetup.sh
including device/fsl/imx7/vendorsetup.sh
including device/fsl/imx8/vendorsetup.sh
including device/generic/car/car-arm64/vendorsetup.sh
including device/generic/car/car-armv7-a-neon/vendorsetup.sh
including device/generic/car/car-x86/vendorsetup.sh
including device/generic/car/car-x86_64/vendorsetup.sh
including device/generic/mini-emulator-arm64/vendorsetup.sh
including device/generic/mini-emulator-armv7-a-neon/vendorsetup.sh
including device/generic/mini-emulator-mips/vendorsetup.sh
including device/generic/mini-emulator-mips64/vendorsetup.sh
including device/generic/mini-emulator-x86/vendorsetup.sh
including device/generic/mini-emulator-x86_64/vendorsetup.sh
including device/google/dragon/vendorsetup.sh
including device/google/marlin/vendorsetup.sh
including device/google/muskie/vendorsetup.sh
including device/google/taimen/vendorsetup.sh
including device/huawei/angler/vendorsetup.sh
including device/lge/bullhead/vendorsetup.sh
including device/linaro/hikey/vendorsetup.sh
including sdk/bash_completion/adb.bash
Setup lunch pioneer_hw1-eng

============================================
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL
PLATFORM_VERSION=8.0.0
TARGET_PRODUCT=pioneer_hw1
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=eng
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_PLATFORM_VERSION=OPD1
TARGET_BUILD_APPS=
TARGET_ARCH=arm
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv7-a-neon
TARGET_CPU_VARIANT=cortex-a9
TARGET_2ND_ARCH=
TARGET_2ND_ARCH_VARIANT=
TARGET_2ND_CPU_VARIANT=
HOST_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_2ND_ARCH=x86
HOST_OS=linux
HOST_OS_EXTRA=Linux-4.15.0-50-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-16.04-xenial
HOST_CROSS_OS=windows
HOST_CROSS_ARCH=x86
HOST_CROSS_2ND_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=1.0.0-rfp-rc4
OUT_DIR=out
AUX_OS_VARIANT_LIST=
============================================
Building with -j16 ...
============================================
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL
PLATFORM_VERSION=8.0.0
TARGET_PRODUCT=pioneer_hw1
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=eng
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_ARCH=arm
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv7-a-neon
TARGET_CPU_VARIANT=cortex-a9
HOST_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_2ND_ARCH=x86
HOST_OS=linux
HOST_OS_EXTRA=Linux-4.15.0-50-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-16.04-xenial
HOST_CROSS_OS=windows
HOST_CROSS_ARCH=x86
HOST_CROSS_2ND_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=1.0.0-rfp-rc4
OUT_DIR=out
============================================
[2/2] bootstrap out/soong/.minibootstrap/build.ninja.in
[1/2] out/soong/.bootstrap/bin/minibp out/soong/.minibootstrap/build.ninja.in
ninja: no work to do.
[2/3] glob device/*/*/Android.bp
ninja: no work to do.
device/fsl/imx6/pioneer_hw1.mk was modified, regenerating...

cts/hostsidetests/os/test-apps/StaticSharedNativeLibProvider/Android.mk:23: warning: FindEmulator: find: `cts/hostsidetests/os/test-apps/StaticSharedNativeLibProvider/src': No such file or directory
cts/hostsidetests/os/test-apps/StaticSharedNativeLibProvider1/Android.mk:23: warning: FindEmulator: find: `cts/hostsidetests/os/test-apps/StaticSharedNativeLibProvider1/src': No such file or directory

./system/sepolicy/Android.mk:107: warning: BOARD_SEPOLICY_VERS not specified, assuming current platform version

No private recovery resources for TARGET_DEVICE pioneer_hw1
platform_testing/build/tasks/tests/instrumentation_metric_test_list.mk: warning: continuous_instrumentation_metric_tests: Unknown installed file for module perf-setup.sh 
platform_testing/build/tasks/tests/instrumentation_test_list.mk: warning: continuous_instrumentation_tests: Unknown installed file for module RecyclerViewTests 
platform_testing/build/tasks/tests/instrumentation_test_list.mk: warning: continuous_instrumentation_tests: Unknown installed file for module SettingsFunctionalTests 
platform_testing/build/tasks/tests/instrumentation_test_list.mk: warning: continuous_instrumentation_tests: Unknown installed file for module LauncherFunctionalTests 
platform_testing/build/tasks/tests/instrumentation_test_list.mk: warning: continuous_instrumentation_tests: Unknown installed file for module EmergencyInfoTests 
platform_testing/build/tasks/tests/native_metric_test_list.mk: warning: continuous_native_metric_tests: Unknown installed file for module perf-setup.sh 
test/vts/tools/build/tasks/vts_package.mk:222: warning: FindEmulator: cd: vendor/google_vts/testcases: No such file or directory
test/vts/tools/build/tasks/vts_package.mk:222: warning: FindEmulator: cd: vendor/google_vts/testcases: No such file or directory
test/vts/tools/build/tasks/vts_package.mk:222: warning: FindEmulator: cd: vendor/google_vts/testcases: No such file or directory
./test/vts/utils/python/archive/Android.mk:28: warning: overriding commands for target `default'
./test/vts/runners/host/tcp_server/Android.mk:19: warning: ignoring old commands for target `default'
build/core/Makefile:34: warning: overriding commands for target `out/target/product/pioneer_hw1/root/init.rc'
build/core/base_rules.mk:378: warning: ignoring old commands for target `out/target/product/pioneer_hw1/root/init.rc'
[ 66% 2/3] glob device/*/*/Android.bp
ninja: error: '.apk', needed by 'device_controller_all_targets', missing and no known rule to make it
16:34:13 ninja failed with: exit status 1
build/core/main.mk:21: recipe for target 'run_soong_ui' failed
make: *** [run_soong_ui] Error 1

#### make failed to build some targets (39 seconds) ####
```

EDIT2: EDIT 2: After putting a space after the controller name, I got *significantly* different results, but still no build:

```
including device/asus/fugu/vendorsetup.sh
including device/fsl/imx6/vendorsetup.sh
including device/fsl/imx7/vendorsetup.sh
including device/fsl/imx8/vendorsetup.sh
including device/generic/car/car-arm64/vendorsetup.sh
including device/generic/car/car-armv7-a-neon/vendorsetup.sh
including device/generic/car/car-x86/vendorsetup.sh
including device/generic/car/car-x86_64/vendorsetup.sh
including device/generic/mini-emulator-arm64/vendorsetup.sh
including device/generic/mini-emulator-armv7-a-neon/vendorsetup.sh
including device/generic/mini-emulator-mips/vendorsetup.sh
including device/generic/mini-emulator-mips64/vendorsetup.sh
including device/generic/mini-emulator-x86/vendorsetup.sh
including device/generic/mini-emulator-x86_64/vendorsetup.sh
including device/google/dragon/vendorsetup.sh
including device/google/marlin/vendorsetup.sh
including device/google/muskie/vendorsetup.sh
including device/google/taimen/vendorsetup.sh
including device/huawei/angler/vendorsetup.sh
including device/lge/bullhead/vendorsetup.sh
including device/linaro/hikey/vendorsetup.sh
including sdk/bash_completion/adb.bash
Setup lunch pioneer_hw1-eng

============================================
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL
PLATFORM_VERSION=8.0.0
TARGET_PRODUCT=pioneer_hw1
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=eng
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_PLATFORM_VERSION=OPD1
TARGET_BUILD_APPS=
TARGET_ARCH=arm
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv7-a-neon
TARGET_CPU_VARIANT=cortex-a9
TARGET_2ND_ARCH=
TARGET_2ND_ARCH_VARIANT=
TARGET_2ND_CPU_VARIANT=
HOST_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_2ND_ARCH=x86
HOST_OS=linux
HOST_OS_EXTRA=Linux-4.15.0-50-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-16.04-xenial
HOST_CROSS_OS=windows
HOST_CROSS_ARCH=x86
HOST_CROSS_2ND_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=1.0.0-rfp-rc4
OUT_DIR=out
AUX_OS_VARIANT_LIST=
============================================
Building with -j16 ...
============================================
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL
PLATFORM_VERSION=8.0.0
TARGET_PRODUCT=pioneer_hw1
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=eng
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_ARCH=arm
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv7-a-neon
TARGET_CPU_VARIANT=cortex-a9
HOST_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_2ND_ARCH=x86
HOST_OS=linux
HOST_OS_EXTRA=Linux-4.15.0-50-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-16.04-xenial
HOST_CROSS_OS=windows
HOST_CROSS_ARCH=x86
HOST_CROSS_2ND_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=1.0.0-rfp-rc4
OUT_DIR=out
============================================
[2/2] bootstrap out/soong/.minibootstrap/build.ninja.in
[2/2] bootstrap out/soong/.minibootstrap/build.ninja.in
ninja: no work to do.
[3/4] glob external/*/Android.bp
ninja: no work to do.
device/fsl/imx6/pioneer_hw1.mk was modified, regenerating...

cts/hostsidetests/os/test-apps/StaticSharedNativeLibProvider/Android.mk:23: warning: FindEmulator: find: `cts/hostsidetests/os/test-apps/StaticSharedNativeLibProvider/src': No such file or directory
cts/hostsidetests/os/test-apps/StaticSharedNativeLibProvider1/Android.mk:23: warning: FindEmulator: find: `cts/hostsidetests/os/test-apps/StaticSharedNativeLibProvider1/src': No such file or directory

./system/sepolicy/Android.mk:107: warning: BOARD_SEPOLICY_VERS not specified, assuming current platform version

No private recovery resources for TARGET_DEVICE pioneer_hw1
platform_testing/build/tasks/tests/instrumentation_metric_test_list.mk: warning: continuous_instrumentation_metric_tests: Unknown installed file for module perf-setup.sh 
platform_testing/build/tasks/tests/instrumentation_test_list.mk: warning: continuous_instrumentation_tests: Unknown installed file for module RecyclerViewTests 
platform_testing/build/tasks/tests/instrumentation_test_list.mk: warning: continuous_instrumentation_tests: Unknown installed file for module SettingsFunctionalTests 
platform_testing/build/tasks/tests/instrumentation_test_list.mk: warning: continuous_instrumentation_tests: Unknown installed file for module LauncherFunctionalTests 
platform_testing/build/tasks/tests/instrumentation_test_list.mk: warning: continuous_instrumentation_tests: Unknown installed file for module EmergencyInfoTests 
platform_testing/build/tasks/tests/native_metric_test_list.mk: warning: continuous_native_metric_tests: Unknown installed file for module perf-setup.sh 
test/vts/tools/build/tasks/vts_package.mk:222: warning: FindEmulator: cd: vendor/google_vts/testcases: No such file or directory
test/vts/tools/build/tasks/vts_package.mk:222: warning: FindEmulator: cd: vendor/google_vts/testcases: No such file or directory
test/vts/tools/build/tasks/vts_package.mk:222: warning: FindEmulator: cd: vendor/google_vts/testcases: No such file or directory
./test/vts/utils/python/archive/Android.mk:28: warning: overriding commands for target `default'
./test/vts/runners/host/tcp_server/Android.mk:19: warning: ignoring old commands for target `default'
build/core/Makefile:34: warning: overriding commands for target `out/target/product/pioneer_hw1/root/init.rc'
build/core/base_rules.mk:378: warning: ignoring old commands for target `out/target/product/pioneer_hw1/root/init.rc'
[ 75% 3/4] glob external/*/Android.bp
ninja: error: '/controller.apk', needed by 'out/target/product/pioneer_hw1/obj/APPS/controller_intermediates/controller.apk', missing and no known rule to make it
15:43:19 ninja failed with: exit status 1
build/core/main.mk:21: recipe for target 'run_soong_ui' failed
make: *** [run_soong_ui] Error 1

#### make failed to build some targets (39 seconds) ####
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be careful you have a typo 
`$(COMMON_ANDROID_PACKAGE_SUFFIIX)` should be `$(COMMON_ANDROID_PACKAGE_SUFFIX)`.

Also make sure you don't have a extra blank space at the end of each line of your external/foo/Android.mk

Comment: I'd fixed that typo after seeing it.  I'm still having the same problem, though.  No difference.    The space, however, made a big difference.  I will put the output of the makefile above under EDIT2.

Comment: The spaces appear to have done it.  No space, no problem.  Thank you much!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your module **foo** is part of the `device.mk` file (e.g device/moto/shamu/device.mk).

```
PRODUCT_PACKAGES += \
    foo
```

This will generate apk in your `system/app` folder. Below flag will take your app to the `system/priv-app` folder.

```
LOCAL_PRIVILEGED_MODULE := true
```

You can also move apk path to vendor partition(`vendor/app`).

```
LOCAL_MODULE_PATH   := $(PRODUCT_OUT)/$(TARGET_COPY_OUT_VENDOR)/app
```

Comment: That certainly got it farther, but it died abruptly:
```
glob external/*/Android.bp
ninja: error: '.apk', needed by 'files', missing and no known rule to make it
14:11:47 ninja failed with: exit status 1
build/core/main.mk:21: recipe for target 'run_soong_ui' failed
make: *** [run_soong_ui] Error 1
```

Comment: Did you try module build(mm)? Or it is failed in full build(make)? Share the complete error logs!!

Comment: [ 66% 2/3] glob device/*/*/Android.bp
ninja: error: '.apk', needed by 'device_controller_all_targets', missing and no known rule to make it
16:34:13 ninja failed with: exit status 1
build/core/main.mk:21: recipe for target 'run_soong_ui' failed
make: *** [run_soong_ui] Error 1

Comment: The rest of the messages, 10s of kilobytes of them, are boilerplate that this distro always generates.  I can put it in an answer, to make it readable, if it will fit.

Comment: So the above question edited with the output of "make foo."  By contrast, "make Launcher3" works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Append your module to `PRODUCT_PACKAGES` in your device makefile,such as :

```
PRODUCT_PACKAGES += \
    foo
```